# How to configure the Kstream state folder

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

By default Kstream uses /tmp location for maintaining its state (kind of metadata) with the app name as as folder name.

[definition of state directory](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams#state-dir)

i faced the below error

```
Caused by: org.rocksdb.RocksDBException: While open a file for appending: /tmp/kafka-streams******** :Disk quota exceeded
```

Answer (score 4):

you can configure the state directory to your desired location by setting it in config object properties in your Kstream definition

https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#state-dir

```
config.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, "/temp2");
```